# Highchart not displaying in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, highcharts, cakephp-2.3

I'm working on one of the cakephp website, where I'm using HighchartPHP libraries. But high-chart is not displaying. This issue is only when I use dynamic data from database, but if I use static array to pass then it will working fine with same code.

Below are array which I get from dynamic code I have used:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [series] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Forwarding Facility 1
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 28.5
                            [1] => 410.68
                            [2] => 0
                            [3] => 0
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Forwarding Facility 2
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 0
                            [2] => 99.05000000000001
                            [3] => 0
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Forwarding Facility 3
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 15.7
                            [2] => 0
                            [3] => 0
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Hampshire Turf
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 540
                            [2] => 0
                            [3] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Below are static data array i used from one of the example from demo :

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [series] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => John
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 5
                            [1] => 3
                            [2] => 4
                            [3] => 7
                            [4] => 2
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Jane
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [1] => 2
                            [2] => 3
                            [3] => 2
                            [4] => 1
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Joe
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 3
                            [1] => 4
                            [2] => 4
                            [3] => 2
                            [4] => 5
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I can't find any solution for the same.

Comment: Any error on JS console?

Comment: No, all the stackes are displaying, xAxis is also displaying. but only bar chart not displaying. :(

Comment: Do you use JSON to return data to javscript?

Comment: i'm using cakephp. so using controller i'm sending data to highchart's php functions.

Comment: Ok, but as a result how your json of data looks like? series obejct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried with lots of different ways, but found very simple solution. **CASTING**.
Yes, somehow its required to TYPE CASTE array value when passing to the highcharts. 
so i use **floatval()** function to convert data into the float value. and finally its working like a charm!

Thank you all for your response and support!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
                        [0] => '0'
                        [1] => '0'
                        [2] => '99.05000000000001'
                        [3] => '0'
```

or your array values as a $something = '99.0500000000001';

```
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 0
                        [2] => $something
                        [3] => 0
```

Comment: No, But if i put this same data in static array then its working fine. no issue without comma(').

Comment: You need to use numbers, not strings.

Comment: Could you preare live demo ?